# Low resolution with kvm switch and amdgpu

Tags: xorg, display-resolution, amdgpu

I'm using a KVM switch to quickly switch between a computer running Ubuntu 18.04 and one running Windows. Switching to the Windows machine works fine. However, when switching back to the Ubuntu machine, the resolution is set to 800x600. Wierdly enough, I'm able to switch to the native resolution with xrandr.
The native resolution of my display is 3840x2160. The Ubuntu machine runs a Radeon RX560 with the open source amdgpu drivers.

Initially I thought it was an issue with EDID info not being sent over by the KVM switch. So I tried adding the EDID blob to /lib/firmware with the drm.edid_firmware cmdline option, but that doesn't seem to help. I've also tried setting the native resolution with video=DP-1:3840x2160@60

Kernel logs when switching to the Windows machine:

```
[  621.586743] [drm] Rx Caps: 
[  621.750368] [drm] Got external EDID base block and 1 extension from "edid/DELL-P2715Q.bin" for connector "DP-1"
[  621.802277] [drm] Unknownx0 EQ failed VS=0, PE=0
[  621.804349] [drm] DELL P2715Q: [Block 0] 
[  621.804350] [drm] DELL P2715Q: [Block 1] 
[  621.804352] [drm] dc_link_detect: manufacturer_id = AC10, product_id = 40BD, serial_number = 33373653, manufacture_week = 23, manufacture_year = 25, display_name = DELL P2715Q, speaker_flag = 1, audio_mode_count = 1
[  621.804353] [drm] dc_link_detect: mode number = 0, format_code = 1, channel_count = 2, sample_rate = 31, sample_size = 7
[  621.808345] [drm:dm_restore_drm_connector_state [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Restoring old state failed with -22
[  621.840311] [drm] {800x600, 1056x625@49500Khz}
[  621.886965] [drm] RBRx1 CR failed VS=0, PE=0
[  621.982017] [drm] RBRx1 CR failed VS=0, PE=0
[  622.126043] [drm] RBRx1 CR failed VS=0, PE=0
```

Kernel logs when switching back to the Ubuntu machine:

```
[  622.322063] [drm] RBRx1 CR failed VS=0, PE=0
[  626.251705] [drm] Rx Caps: 
[  626.253741] [drm] Got external EDID base block and 1 extension from "edid/DELL-P2715Q.bin" for connector "DP-1"
[  626.260101] [drm] HBR2x4 pass VS=1, PE=1
[  626.260408] [drm] DELL P2715Q: [Block 0] 
[  626.260409] [drm] DELL P2715Q: [Block 1] 
[  626.260411] [drm] dc_link_detect: manufacturer_id = AC10, product_id = 40BD, serial_number = 33373653, manufacture_week = 23, manufacture_year = 25, display_name = DELL P2715Q, speaker_flag = 1, audio_mode_count = 1
[  626.260412] [drm] dc_link_detect: mode number = 0, format_code = 1, channel_count = 2, sample_rate = 31, sample_size = 7
[  626.261282] [drm] {800x600, 1056x625@49500Khz}
```

And finally when switching to the native resolution with xrandr:

```
[  626.289617] [drm] RBRx1 pass VS=1, PE=1
[  633.990747] [drm] {3840x2160, 4000x2222@533250Khz}
```

In Xorg.0.log I get a list of modelines (including the native one), and then:

```
[   626.422] (EE) AMDGPU(0): failed to set mode: Permission denied
```

Is this an issue with kms or Xorg?

Any help on resolving this would be much appreciated. Currently I'm running xrandr manually after switching, which is rather tedious.

Comment: AFAIK The KVM tag is meant for KVM virtualization, not KVM switches - you might want to drop that.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt: Thanks, removed the kvm tag.